# How do I know if I have a short circuit

Tags: arduino-uno, breadboard

I just got my first arduino starters kit so I'm a total noob in it. My simple LED blinker did work, afterwards I used a switch button with a debouncer script. It worked like I wanted but I wanted to try a buzzer instead of the LED, which did not work. Afterwards when I put the LED back in it didn't work anymore either.

The onboard LED does still work. Does this mean my breadboard had a short circuit? Is there any way I can know this for sure? And what exactly went wrong? Did I have to use a higher resistor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend using a digital multimeter in this case. They are not too expensive and a must for electrical projects. Most have functions such as checking for shorts. In addition, you can check to see if the pin in question changes voltage when activated. The thing to remember is that heat kills electrical components, and high current causes heat (high power, really, but watch your current and you will be fine) get familiar with the formula v=I/R and don't put too much current through your buzzer or LED. LEDs have very little resistance.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I should have a multimeter somewhere I will try it out. I thought my programming knowledge would be enough for Arduino but I think that won't cut it I will indeed look up and learn more about it.